# Extjs 4.2 How to check if current Node Has children nodes?

Tags: extjs, treepanel

I have a treepanel in extjs 4.2 when user click a node I want to know if clicked node is a child or parent? OR if it has any children?

- A
- ->x
- ->y
- ->z
- B
- ->w
- ->r

I want (B) absolute index (1) (A->0,B->1) but the 'indexOf' return (B)->4 it counts the children of A also, how can I get the absolute index '1' of B?

Thank you,

Comment: check [hasChildNodes](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-hasChildNodes)

Comment: Got it-) if child how can I get parent index (0,1,2...)? thanx

Comment: check [parentNode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-property-parentNode)

Comment: Thank you very much...One more question the 'indexOf(ND.parentNode)' return the index of parent node BUT not the absolute index it returns the relevant index, please see question I updated it.

Comment: try `tree.getRootNode().indexOf(node)`

Comment: you can also try with tree.getRootNode().findChild() method, it returns node interface